# Why is my player still moving down when I set its gravity to 0?

Tags: physics, phaser

I'm writing [Lode Runner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lode_Runner) like platformer game. I'm trying to solve player sprite slowly moving down when on ladder by setting `player.body.gravity.y = 0`. I have arcade physics gravity y set to 900 in game config. But game gravity settings seems to override `player.body.gravity` settings.

I even log `player.body.gravity.y` to console. It shows 0 when player is on ladder. But it still slowly moving down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#gravity__anchor) page, it looks like the total gravity for a body is the one you set the way you did for your body, added to the global gravity:

> **gravity :Phaser.Math.Vector2**
>
> Acceleration due to gravity (specific to this Body), in pixels per second squared. Total gravity is the sum of this vector and the simulation's gravity.

I haven't worked with Phaser 3, but I guess that, since the total gravity is a *sum* of values, you'd want to set the gravity for your player to -900 to counteract the effect of the gravity.

Alternatively, if you just want to disable the gravity for your object, it looks like you could do it through the `setAllowGravity(true/false)` function, as described [here](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#setAllowGravity__anchor).

As an example, you can take a look at [this sandbox](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/physics/arcade/gravity.js&v=3.18.1), setting the gravity to `-60` at line 38 will make the second box stay still.

Comment: https://platformergametest.000webhostapp.com/ here's the game I hosted on free hosting.

Can you check why is my player is freezed on the top ladder (appers when collected all chests) ? Sometimes I'm able to climb and sometimes not. Also when I get to the top of the ladder player is still jumping a little bit. I have no idea how to fix it. And if I set gravity to -900 while on ladder I'm not able to go left and right when I reach the top. I think I made some foundamental mistake in the conception of control management.

Sorry for asking too many questions but I don't want to make new post

Comment: @Madcap This appears to be a different question. Comments are not a great place to ask new questions ao I suggest you create a new question post including the code you've used.

Comment: Thanks again! How to mark my question answered and close the topic ?

Comment: @Madcap Below the up-down arrows, there should be a greyed out check-mark. Clicking this will mark this answer as "Accepted", which will indicate to other visitors that this one was the most helpful in solving your issue. You don't _have_ to do this, but it's useful for future users. Also, the "closed" status is for questions that are considered off-topic for this site. Your question being on topic here, it does not need to be "closed"; the "accepted" status will be more than enough :)